# Slack Real-Time-Messaging websocket

Tags: android, websocket, slack-api, java-websocket, androidasync-koush

Trying to implement this in application. [Slack RTM](https://api.slack.com/rtm)
After call to rtm.start I get JSON-response and extract wss url. After it, following documentation I need to open websocket. 
Tried two libraries

```
compile 'com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.+'
compile 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'
```

First gives TimeoutException, second - enters onClose method with i = -1, b = true (onError or onOpen are not called, see code below).

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(getQuery(URL + "rtm.start",
                                new Pair<>("token", TOKEN))).openConnection();
final String response = readIs(connection.getInputStream());
JSONObject jResponse = new JSONObject(response); 
String uri = (String) jResponse.get("url");
```

With Java-WebSocket I've tried this code (standard from example on github):

```
connectWebSocket(uri);

private void connectWebSocket(String uriStr) {
        URI uri;
        try {
            uri = new URI(uriStr);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        log(uri.toString());
        log(uri.toASCIIString());

        mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
            @Override
            public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
                log("Opened");
                mWebSocketClient.send("Hello from " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String s) {
                log(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
                log("Closed " + s + " " + b + " number: " + i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                log("Error " + e.getMessage());
            }
        };
        mWebSocketClient.connect();
    }
```

As I've said above - only onClose is called.

With AndroidAsync tried standard code from example too:

```
AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance().websocket(uri, "wss", (ex, webSocket) -> {
        if (ex != null) {
            log(ex.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        webSocket.send("a string");
});
```

I've never worked with websockets on android before, and can't understand what am I doing wrong. Will appreciate your help.

Url in JSON is of type of

```
wss://ms156.slack-msgs.com/websocket/LYBUMUtG-bqj9HkKwEB5Yk_DCyPeRbnZ4viUJYHzrzJnLr-M74d46IQ9khTF8rik-v6ckJ4hqXPRi666hyPR6pismYBZBsggJUade3LOARc=
```

Comment: any results on this @Yaroslav?

Comment: @sirvon yes, I provided answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally my coleague managed to open this socket using OkHttp. If somebody is interested - code of test project is provided below:
http://pastebin.com/3YhLjAn7
What is interesting - in the end we decided not to use RTM, because load for one connection is too high - you receive events from all chats and there is no way to set filter only for one specific.